# URL manipulation in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to write a protractor test that allows me to log in to the application. Currently, when i authorize my account, oauth generates an authentication token, and gives it to me in a https format. As of right now, the only way i can access the application is to simply take the "s" out of the https in the URL, and i will be able to access the app.

an example of the URL that is returned when i authorize my account is :

```
https://localhost:3000/#/authorize?oauth_token=escgPGm9si5N
```

All i want to do is have protractor take the secure connection URL, delete the s in https, and keep everything else and use that to keep moving. Since the authentication token changes every time, i cant store it as a variable. I am pretty sure I will have to use browser.getCurrentUrl, but i don't know what to do next. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to throw the "s" out of the https, you'll be good with below:

```
browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
    //here the url is just a string!
    var correctUrl = url.replace("https", "http");

    //now you can do whatever with the correct url, like go to it
    browser.get(correctUrl);
});
```

Please let know if you need anything more.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. It seems like your code is working!

Comment: Great, happy to help :)